# Displaying labels with different background color in grouped tableView ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitableview

[image]

Hi friends. i Need to display the labels in a UItableView. How can i do that.
Kindly refer the screenshot.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: and where exactly is the problem in implementing this tableView? Having labels in a UITableViewCell is among the most basic things you can do on iOS.

Comment: @ManojEllappan Show us some code please.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` style of UITableViewCell. Use Custom view for the section header.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 22.0f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UILabel *sectionLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    sectionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];//Choose your color
    sectionLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    sectionLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0f];
    sectionLabel.text = @"Section Name";

    return sectionLabel;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //Default detailTextLabel would have blue text color change it to your choice
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Mobile Number";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Type";

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellsToBeReused = @"CellsToBeReused";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellsToBeReused];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellsToBeReused] autorelease]; 
    }


        UILabel* Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2,2, 62, 23)];
        [Label setText:@"Text"];
        Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:Label];
        [Label release];

        return cell;        

}
```

Comment: ok frnd.. and i have to insert two labels in a section.. that is, label "email" and another label to hold its value.. so there must be different sections for each label-value pair right? how to insert that label-value pair into each section..

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewDelegate has a method -

`(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

You could simply return a customized UILabel

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewCell` objects have a `contentView` property. Add any custom views as `subviews` of `contentView`.
What you want is a `Custom UITableViewCell`. If you Google for that, you'll find a lot of Tutorials and Information.

**For example :**

1. [Custom UITableViewCell in IB](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/).
2. [Custom UITableViewCell Using Interface Builder](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/).

Answer (score 1):

Its better you go thorough with UITableView. Apple is the best resource

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html

Hope this helps !!!